# R: Looping and syntax when grouping rows

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

My data is 18 rows by 8 columns. It contains both numerical and word data. I want to assing each row an ID number. I want to group the rows with the same info in the first 5 columns by the same ID number. For some reason I don't think I am looping properly. Any thoughts?

```
sampdata<-read.csv("xxx")

sampdata["ID"] <- 0 #ID column

count<-1 #to subtract from 10000

for (p in 1:18) {

if (sampdata[p,9] == 0){ 

count<-count+1

sampdata[9,p]<-10000-count

for (i in 1:5){ #column index for current check (only check defining info)

  for (j in 1:18) { #row index for current check

    for (k in 1:18){ #column index for current check against

      if (sampdata[i,j]==sampdata[i,k])

        sampdata[j,9]<-sampdata[9,p] #assign same ID number


    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: This is most likely not a very R-idiomatic way of doing what you want to do. Can you provide sample data (e.g. using `dput(head(sampdata,20))`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks something like this

```
mm<-matrix(c(
1,1,2,2,3, 1,1,2,2,3,
2,2,2,3,3, 2,2,2,3,3,
4,3,2,1,2, 1,1,2,2,3,
3,1,1,2,2
), byrow=T, ncol=5)

dd<-data.frame(mm[,1:3], 
    X4=letters[mm[,4]], X5=mm[,5], 
    matrix(runif(nrow(mm)*(18-ncol(mm))), nrow=nrow(mm)))
```

Where your data is in `dd` and the first 5 columns define a group. You can use `interaction()` to assign a unique ID to each group like this

```
dd$ID <- as.numeric(interaction(dd[,1:5], drop=T, lex.order=T))
```

Comment: Will this work if the data is not all numeric? I.e: one column gives states for each row

Comment: This sample includes non-numeric values. So yes. It will work.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! Now that I know this method works, I'd like to be able to run this program on a data set thats around 7 columns by 225,000. Unfortunately R studio cannot import files that big. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can run this method on a set that big without mannually breaking it up?

Comment: I'm surprised it cannot read your file. You must not have much RAM. Anyway, that's a completely different question. Better to start a new post.